# Adding text after subfigures in Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am writing my master thesis in Latex and I am getting the following error. I am adding three subplots and then some text but I am having the issue where the text does not come after the images but before. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
  \centering
  \subfloat[Absolute correlations of initial states in case A]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Images/Results/correlation_best.png}}

  \subfloat[Absolute correlations of initial states of Callisto and Jupiter in case B]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Images/Results/correlations_vlbi.png}}
  
  \subfloat[Absolute correlations of initial states of Callisto and Jupiter in case C]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Images/Results/correlations_worst.png}}
  \caption{Absolute correlations for Callisto and Jupiter}
\end{figure}
We highlight case B and case C
```

Here you can find attached the issue I am getting.[image]

Comment: That's expected. There is not enough space to place the image at the position where you inserted it, so latex uses its floating mechanism to find a good spot later in the document. That's really a good thing because it avoids excessive white space at all the places where the images don't fit.